# Add items to ListView only if item is not a duplicate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have been spinning my wheels on this one for days!

Trying to add the `MainWindowTitle` of a specific currently running processes by process name, in this example "notepad", to a ListView.  I have figured out how to create and add the item, but now I have duplicates in my ListView.  So what I'm trying to do is only add an item to my ListView if it doesn't already exist as an exact item on my ListView.

Relevant information:

-There will be multiple of the same processes that I am trying to capture the MainWindowTitle from (from 1 to 9) but they will each have a unique ID.

-Each MainWindowTitle will be different

Here's what I have so far, I can't make LINQ work and I'm not sure if there would be a way to make a foreach loop to prevent duplicates.

I appreciate any help!

```
Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    foreach (Process process in processList)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Content = process.MainWindowTitle;
        item.Tag = process;

        if (listView.Items.Contains(item))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New Item!");
            listView.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Edit 1: Still adding duplicate items

```
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        foreach (Process process in processList)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Content = process.MainWindowTitle;

            item.DataContext = process;

            var itemz = listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList().Where(x => x.DataContext == process);

            if (listView.Items.Contains(itemz))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New Item!");
                listView.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

Edit2: Closer, I hope, still adding duplicates

```
        Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
        foreach (Process process in processList)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Content = process.MainWindowTitle;

            item.DataContext = process;

            var itemz = listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList().Where(x => (x.DataContext as Process).Id == process.Id);

            if (itemz == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("New Item!");
                listView.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually populating the `ListView` with items create an `ObservableCollection<string>` that contains the unique window titles that you want to display. Then set the `ListView.ItemsSource` to this property. On this backing collection just make sure to only add something if it is distinct. So something like this:

**View Model**

```
public class ValuesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> WindowTitles { get; private set; }

    public ValuesViewModel()
    {
        WindowTitles = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public void AddTitleIfUnique(string title)
    {
        if (!WindowTitles.Contains(title))
            WindowTitles.Add(title);
    }
}
```

**UI XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding WindowTitles}"/>
```

**UI Code Behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new ValuesViewModel();
        viewModel.AddTitleIfUnique("Testing");
        viewModel.AddTitleIfUnique("Testing Again");
        viewModel.AddTitleIfUnique("Testing Again");
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Where the `MainWindow` is assumed to contain the `ListView` UI XAML chunk in its XAML. This shows the result that I think you are looking for. Basically I have moved the logic of adding if unique back to the view model and out of the view like you have it in your question this makes implementing the logic simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for this code not working is that ListViewItem doesn't overload the equals operator. If this is the case then when you call Contains it is checking if the objects are the same object which is never the case because you just created the new one. To insure uniqueness I would use the linq Any function instead of Contains. Linq Any checks to see if there are any elements that match the given condition.

```
if (listView.Items.Contains(item))//replace this
if(listView.Items.Any(x=>x.Content == item.Content))//with this
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, someone on another forum had suggested that, unfortunately, 'ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any'.

Comment: Are you `using System.Linq;` Linq functions require that using statement to work.

Comment: Yes, using System.Linq;
Still a new programmer overall, and new to c#, but .contains appears to call an 'object' and I believe that is why Any is unusable

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Process object as the DataContext of the ListViewItem. Then, use Process.Id to check if the item is already added.

```
var item = listview.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList().Where(x => x.DataContext == theProcess);
```

Comment: I would very much appreciate an example, I am unable to trip the if statement with the above information

Comment: I have added sample.

Comment: Still very new to c#, this looks promising, although, I'm not sure how to use this.  Am I replacing some lines with this, or this should be my new if statement?
Also, what does 'theProcess' represent in relation to my code?
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I just preferred DataContext instead of the Tag from your code. But the idea is the same as yours prior to your 'if'. Now, when you check if it exist, use my sample.. this time, use the ID of the Process object. The item (from var item = ...)  will return null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think I'm still not quite grasping the concept:  please see edit 1

Comment: Stay away from contains() ... if itemz is not null, duplicate, otherwise, not! edit this .....Where(x => (x.DataContext as Process).Id == process.Id);

Comment: Closer, I think, still adding duplicates though: edit2

Comment: It looks like your code is different  from what I told you from my last comment. Also, you have to create a new ListViewItem only if you're sure that the item is not created yet.